# For QNetworkAccessManager:: post, why can the second parameter use QIODevice or QHttpMultiPart to save memory?

Tags: c++, qt

```
QNetworkReply *QNetworkAccessManager::post(const QNetworkRequest &request, QIODevice *data);
QNetworkReply *QNetworkAccessManager::post(const QNetworkRequest &request, const QByteArray &data);
QNetworkReply *QNetworkAccessManager::post(const QNetworkRequest &request, QHttpMultiPart *multiPart);
```

I know that to use **QByteArray**, you must first copy all the files into memory. If the file is larger than 1G, it may cause the program to crash, and the upload speed will be slow, which is not applicable to sending large files.

The last overloaded function adds QHttpPart to QHttpMultiPart when transferring large files. It usually uses `void QHttpPart::setBodyDevice(QIODevice * device)` instead of `void QHttpPart::setBody (const QByteArray&body)`.

I understand stream operations and buffers in C++.The file read can read all contents in sequence according to the buffer size.Does QIODevice do the same?Is it also achieved by maintaining a buffer?

Comment: No offense, just a hint: Did you read the description of [QIODevice](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qiodevice.html#details)? To cite from this link: _QIODevice provides ... an abstract interface for devices_ and later: _Some subclasses, such as QFile and QTcpSocket, are implemented using a memory buffer for intermediate storing of data_

Comment: I checked the documents in Qt Creator again, and I really ignored this sentence. So this is why using the first and second overloaded functions to upload large files, and using the subclass of QIODevice with buffer, such as QFile, will not cause memory overflow.  @Scheff'sCat